# Writing function using *args to create a new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie to pandas and I want to know how to create a new column in dataframe by applying a function using *args on specific columns..

Following is my dataframe:

```
pri  pri_loc sec       s0  s0_loc  s1   s1_loc  s2   s2_loc
ABC  7       AB,BC,CA  AB  7       BC   7       CA   7
PQR  12      PQ,QR     PQ  NaN     QR   12      NaN  NaN
LMN  21      LM,MN,NM  LM  NaN     MN   NaN     NM   NaN
XYZ  5       ZX,YX,YZ  ZX  18      YX   25      YZ   34
RST  10      RT,ST     RT  50      ST   10      NaN  NaN
EFG  2       EF        EF  2       NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
SRT  8       RK        RK  10      NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
MSD  7       SD        SD  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
VK   18      NaN       NaN NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
```

I want to create a new column called comp_loc, by passing values of pri_loc,s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc columns to function compare_loc which does the following:

1. if  (all of s0_loc, s1_loc and s2_loc) == (value of pri_loc) then it should return 'same'
2. if (all of s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc) is NULL then it should return 'doubt'
3. if (any one of s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc == pri_loc and if any other != pri_loc) then it should return doubt
4. if (all of s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc != pri_loc) it should return not same

**Note that** I want to send s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc to compare_loc if and only if values in s0,s1,s2 is not null.
For Eg.(if s0 is null, s0_loc should not be sent to compare_loc function... Similarly if s1 is null s1_loc should not be sent and if s2 is null s2_loc should not be sent)

Following is output dataframe:

```
   pri  pri_loc sec       s0  s0_loc  s1   s1_loc  s2   s2_loc  comp_loc
0  ABC  7       AB,BC,CA  AB  7       BC   7       CA   7       same
1  PQR  12      PQ,QR     PQ  NaN     QR   12      NaN  NaN     doubt
2  LMN  21      LM,MN,NM  LM  NaN     MN   NaN     NM   NaN     doubt
3  XYZ  5       ZX,YX,YZ  ZX  18      YX   25      YZ   34      not same
4  RST  10      RT,ST     RT  50      ST   10      NaN  NaN     doubt
5  EFG  2       EF        EF  2       NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     same
6  SRT  8       RK        RK  10      NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     not same
7  MSD  7       SD        SD  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     doubt
8  VK   18      NaN       NaN NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve this..??
Btw I'm trying to write a function using ***args**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the functions which i've used to achieve the desired output:

```
def isnan(value):
    try:
        return math.isnan(float(value))
    except:
        return False

def compare(p_loc,*args):
    fs = 0
    fns = 0
    fnan1 = 0
    fnan2 = 0
    fd1=0
    fd2=0
    if isnan(p_loc):
       return 'doubt'
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if v != p_loc:
            fs = 1
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if v == p_loc:
            fns = 1
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if isnan(v):
            fnan1 = 1
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if isnan(v):
            fnan2 = 1
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if v == p_loc:
            fd1 = 1
    for k,v in enumerate(args):
        if v != p_loc:
            fd2 = 1
    if fs ==0:
        return 'same'
    if fnan1 == 1:
        return 'doubt'
    elif (fd1 == 1 and fd2 == 1) and (fnan2 == 0):
        return 'doubt'
    elif fns == 0:
        return 'not same'    


def compare_locality(p,p_loc,s0,s0_loc,s1,s1_loc,s2,s2_loc):
    loc = []
    if not isnan(s0) :
        loc.append(s0_loc)
        if not isnan(s1) :
            loc.append(s1_loc)
            if not isnan(s2) :
                loc.append(s2_loc)
    if len(loc) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return compare(p_loc,*loc)
```

Following line invokes the above function and creates a new column:

```
data['comp_loc'] = data.apply(lambda x: compare_locality(x['pri'],x['pri_loc'],x['s0'],x['s0_loc'],x['s1'],x['s1_loc'],x['s2'],x['s2_loc']),axis=1)
```